# How To Translate Assembly Code Back Into C?

Tags: c, assembly, x86-64, reverse-engineering

I saw the following assembly code (note I added the notes by myself):

```
00000000004005f0 <check_password>:
  4005f0:   31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax          # i=0
  4005f2:   66 0f 1f 44 00 00       nopw   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)   # ignore
  4005f8:   0f b6 90 c0 1b 40 00    movzbl 0x401bc0(%rax),%edx# edx=foo[i]
  4005ff:   83 f2 5f                xor    $0x5f,%edx
  400602:   38 14 07                cmp    %dl,(%rdi,%rax,1)  # cmp prev result with s[i]
  400605:   75 14                   jne    40061b <check_password+0x2b> # failed return 0
  400607:   48 83 c0 01             add    $0x1,%rax          # i++
  40060b:   48 83 f8 0a             cmp    $0xa,%rax          # if (i==10)
  40060f:   75 e7                   jne    4005f8 <check_password+0x8> # run again
  400611:   31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
  400613:   80 7f 0a 00             cmpb   $0x0,0xa(%rdi) 
  400617:   0f 94 c0                sete   %al
  40061a:   c3                      retq   
  40061b:   31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
  40061d:   c3                      retq
```

and want to write the equivalent C code to fill this:

Edit1:

```
int check_password (char *s)
{
    for (int i=0; i!=10 ; i++)
    {
        if (foo[i] ^ 0x5f != s[i])
            return 0;
    }
    return 0==s[10]; // Isn't this strange? input is of size 10...
}
```

Edit 2:

```
int check_password (char *s)
{
    for (int i=0; i!=10 ; i++)
    {
        if (foo[i] ^ 0x5f != s[i])
            return 0==s[10]; // Isn't this strange? input is of size 10...
    }
    return 1;
}
```

I feel too close to get it but got stuck a little, is version 1 right or 2 or none of them.
Plus, what should be the correct translation here?

Some important things to know:

I have the following array of chars called foo which is located at address `401bc0` in memory.

```
char foo[10] = { 0x33, 0x3d, ...... }; // Not all values are shown
```

Comment: Explain "stuck a little" in technical terms, please.

Comment: You're looking for a [decompiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decompiler).

Comment: Can you actually remove the `__`s? The code you have written here is really hard to read let alone execute and test

Comment: Please don't edit the question, add an answer or new code with edits. It invalidates the discussions in chat and makes it harder for future readers to understand the question

Comment: Because you edited your question to make them invalid and wrong.

Comment: I thought this looked familiar; this the same code as the OP's previous (now deleted) question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67730954/how-to-translate-this-assembly-code-into-c, with the cmp/sete check for reaching the end of the implicit-length C string handled correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you look at actual compiler output to see if GCC reconstructs the same asm with either of your versions?  https://godbolt.org/z/ed86jG9rf shows both the almost-right and the wrong versions.  (I'm intentionally not saying here which one is right, so you have to go look for yourself, although the difference seems pretty obvious to me between having the cmp/sete in the fall-through path or in the mismatch path.  Also, do you see any asm that would unconditionally returns `1`?  How about `0`?)

Notice that one of them compiles back to your asm with GCC5.4, after you fix your operator-precedence bug: `foo[i] ^ 0x5f != s[i]` means `foo[i] ^ (0x5f != s[i])`, i.e. XOR with a bool, so the if would be true/false based on the low bit of the XOR result.  You actually `(pass[i] ^ 0xf5) != s[i]` to compare the XOR result.

I only noticed this from the asm being weird (with cmp / setne *inside* the loop), so I turned on `-Wall` and GCC told me what was going on.

```
<source>:19:28: warning: suggest parentheses around comparison in operand of '^' [-Wparentheses]
         if (pass[i] ^ 0x5f != s[i])
                            ^
```

We have very good tools for compiling C; take advantage of them when writing C for any reason, including reverse engineering from asm.  Especially for code you know was compiler-generated, especially if you can guess the compiler.  x86-64 with the System V calling convention (arg in RDI) is usually GCC or clang.  In this case they both make quite similar asm, if you use `-fno-unroll-loops` with clang.

---

> `return 0==s[10]; // Isn't this strange? input is of size 10...`

Seems normal (but inefficient) to me: apparently the static `const char pass[]` doesn't end with a `0 ^ 0x5f` terminator.  Otherwise they could just let the loop run for one more iteration to check that the input implicit-length C string function arg has a 0 terminator after its 10 matching bytes.

This final check will reject passwords that have trailing garbage after the first 10 bytes, but matched up to that point.

So that means it's expecting `strlen(s) == 10`, i.e. a `char [11]` to hold 10 bytes plus a terminating 0.

Answer (score -2):

From past experience doing this sort of thing, a process of successive refinement is in order.   so first write it like fortran:

```
check_password(char *rdi) {

     int  eax = 0;
     char *str = (char *)0x401bc0;
loop:
     char dl = str[eax];
     dl ^= 0x5f;
     if (dl == rdi[eax]) {
         eax++;
         if (eax == 10) {
              return rdi[10] == 0;
         }
         goto loop;
      }
      return 0;
}
```

Before advancing to a more C-ish:

```
char *str = (char *)0x401bc0;
int check_password(char *rdi) {
     int i;
     for (i = 0; i < 10 && rdi[i] == str[i]^0x5f; i++) {
     }
     return i == 10 && rdi[i] == 0;
}
```

Not terrifically essential for this, but as the branching from asm gets intense, C-goto is your friend; once you have reduced it, detecting the structured patterns is typically straightforward.
In one instance, I distilled a 900 line lump of assembly nobody understood into 80 lines of C.  It was then propagated over 6 architectures, and every one had a 10 - 30 % speed bump, and all of it in the longest interrupt off time of the kernel.

Comment: Sorry but this isn't what I am looking for, no need to all those variables my code needs one tiny fix...

Comment: It's not global `char *str`, it's global `char str[]`; note that it's directly indexing the static array, not loading a pointer from static storage and indexing that.  Also, some of the types don't fully match the asm.  `add $1, %rax` indicates that it's `size_t i`, not `int`.  The zero-extending load from the global array could be represented as `unsigned c = pass[i]`, although that's just GCC avoiding false dependencies; if we know it's `char*`, not `unsigned char*`, then the local var must be `char dl`, otherwise GCC would have done a sign-extending load.

Comment: Your general approach of starting with C gotos is reasonable, but your final result is farther from the asm than necessary.  e.g. the source asm doesn't do something like `return i == 10 && rdi[i] == 0;` - instead it has two separate ways to leave the the loop: mismatch and fallthrough.  Only fallthrough still needs extra checking for what the return value should be, since apparently the global `str[]` isn't terminated with a 0x5f, so they couldn't just loop another iteration to check that that matches.  Needs more code for little benefit.

Comment: I think a clearer intermediate form would be a do{}while loop - that's the structure of the asm.  And representing the loop branch as `if(eax == 10) return` with a fall-through to `goto loop` is quite confusing and unintuitive.  That's not at all how I'd think about this asm.  I don't think mosh's objection about introducing new variables is valid in general; if your answer had gone on to eliminate them in a way that still worked like the asm, or like the C template with `___` blanks the OP was supposed to fill in, that would be fine.  But instead you've obfuscated and transformed the logic.

Comment: (Correction to my earlier comment: `int i` does compile to `add $1, %rax` in https://godbolt.org/z/ed86jG9rf - GCC is widening to pointer width to avoid redoing sign-extension (allowed because signed overflow is UB).  Of course, this is only because GCC is dumb and doesn't see the upper bound on the loop that means it would be safe to use 32-bit operand-size, not wasting a REX.